# C++ Access violation when setting XMMATRIX

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11

I'm getting the error

> Unhandled exception at 0x013D2841 in Reece's Prototype.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFF.

When the line below runs

```
world_matrix = _rotation * _position * _scale;
```

All of the above variables are of type XMMATRIX.

I only get this error when I use `new` (I want to have an array of objects which I then iterate over and render).

Comment: Where's the sample code which throws that error?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you should not try to allocate XMMATRIX on the heapMemory using `new` operator

XMMATRIX are platform specific type, it seems that this type is aligned in a 16 byte format on the stack and it suggested to do so in the heap:

> For this reason, DirectXMath operations using XMVECTOR and XMMATRIX objects assume those objects are 16-byte aligned. This is automatic for stack based allocations, if code is compiled against the DirectXMath Library using the recommended Windows (see Use Correct Compilation Settings) compiler settings. However, it is important to ensure that heap-allocation containing XMVECTOR and XMMATRIX objects, or casts to these types, meet these alignment requirements.

If you want to create a default object try:

```
XMMATRIX mat = XMMatrixIdentity();
```